# ERROR: FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do a query to get all details from a table such that no two of the fields (s/p/j) are located in the same city.

```
select 
     S.s
     ,PJ.p
     ,PJ.j
from date.s S
     full outer join(
          select 
               P.p as p
               ,P.city as pcity
               ,J.j as j
               ,J.city as jcity
          from date.p P
               full outer join date.j J on P.city = J.city where J.city is null 
     )as PJ on S.city = PJ.pcity or S.city = PJ.jcity
where 
     PJ.pcity is null 
     or PJ.jcity is null
```

However, on executing the code above this error is occuring

> ERROR:  FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or
>   hash-joinable join conditions

Comment: mysql or postgres? choose only one

Comment: I'm using postgres. edited

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and desire output. Not sure what that error mean, but im sure you can make the query with simple `JOIN`   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
  
  And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: `where J.city is null` This can be rewritten into a not exists() construct IIUC. (but the `J.city` is also exported to the outer query, which will reduce to a NOT EXISTS(), too IIUC.

Comment: This seems derived from Chris Date's 17.1. Please add the table definitions and the exact goal, *get all details from a table* is a bit vague. (problem looks like a kind of relational division)